# Screen capture app with audio

Tags: applications

Does the Android OS allow for screen recording with audio? Is there an app that can do this?

I have been using android debug bridge to capture video of the screen, but that comes without audio.

I have tried a couple apps , but have not found any that do audio. I found one that uses the mic to record the speaker, which is obviously pretty crappy.

Comment: What is the source of audio? an application in your Android or something other than your device?

Answer (score 0):

To create promo videos of my apps, I use [ScreenRecorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nll.screenrecorder). It allows you to record with audio and maintains screen orientation of the app being recorded. I don't think your device has to be rooted. It has a high rating and over 10 million downloads.

Answer (score 0):

If your phone doesnt have an internal recording support then I have an easy alternative.
Okay! This ones pretty simple, there are only 2 things you need:

- Earphone With control button
- Strong Clip

> Before you record you will need to clip the button(Make sure the button is clicked) to your earphones. It will promp you to a google assistant but clicking away should avoid the problem. After that enable the sound recording to your Screen recorder software and it should record your device's internal audio without any of the outside noise.